# Output Value from select-object calculated value

Tags: object, powershell, select, key-value

I've used a hash table to calculate some values for my VMWare inventory script, but now when I output the data, it records it as a key/value pair. I'd like to dump just the value. When I simply take what I'm handed that works fine, but when I get picky PS starts to stonewall me. :-)

Here is the relevant part of the script.

```
foreach ($machine in $vmList) {    
  $vmname = $machine.Name
  $properties = @{
     'Name'=Get-VM $vmname | Select -ExpandProperty Name
     'RAM'=Get-VM $vmname | Select -ExpandProperty MemoryGB
     'CpuCount'=Get-VM $vmname | Select -ExpandProperty NumCpu
     'UsedDiskGB'=Get-VM $vmname | Select-Object @{n="UsedDiskGB"; e={[math]::Round( $_.UsedSpaceGB, 3 )}}
     'TotalDiskGB'=Get-VM $vmname | Select-Object @{n="TotalDiskGB"; e={[math]::Round((Get-HardDisk -vm $_ | Measure-Object -Sum CapacityGB).Sum)}}
     'Networks'=Get-VM $vmname | Select-Object @{n="Networks"; e={(Get-NetworkAdapter -VM $_ |Sort-Object NetworkName |Select -Unique -Expand NetworkName) -join '; '}}
     'OS'=(Get-VM -Name $vmname | Get-View).summary.config.guestFullName
  }
  $object=New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Prop $properties

  Export-Csv -Path $WorkDir\vms.csv -Append -Encoding UTF8 -InputObject $Object 
  Write-Output $Object
}
```

How do I get UsedDiskGB, Networks and TotalDiskGB to display just the value instead of something like '@{TotalDiskGB=80}'? Ram, OS, CpuCount and Name work exactly as desired already.

Also, suggestions on doing this in a faster way are welcome. I'm sure all these calls can be done better. I had it done in a single line, but then they asked for OS to be added and that changed everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy, but bad way:
In the expression pipe to `|Select -ExpandProperty <property name>` to get just the value. Such as:

```
'TotalDiskGB'=Get-VM $vmname | Select-Object @{n="TotalDiskGB"; e={[math]::Round((Get-HardDisk -vm $_ | Measure-Object -Sum CapacityGB).Sum)}}|select -expand totaldiskgb
```

The better way:
Structure your properties better to start with. Try this:

```
'TotalDiskGB'= [math]::Round((Get-HardDisk -vm (Get-VM $vmname) | Measure-Object -Sum CapacityGB).Sum)
```

The reason you're having issues is because you are creating a PSCustomObject with your Select, and Totaldiskgb is a property of that object. You don't want to make an object, you just want the value of that property.

**Edit:** Thank you to @briantist for pointing out that `Get-VM $vmname` should be called once, and stored as an object to be used later, rather than called for each time it is needed for a member of `$Properties`. For example:

```
foreach ($machine in $vmList) {    
  $vmname = $machine.Name
  $vmobject = Get-VM $vmname
  $properties = @{
     'Name'=$vmobject | Select -ExpandProperty Name
     'RAM'=$vmobject | Select -ExpandProperty MemoryGB
     'CpuCount'=$vmobject | Select -ExpandProperty NumCpu
     'UsedDiskGB'=[math]::Round( $vmobject.UsedSpaceGB, 3 )
     'TotalDiskGB'=[math]::Round((Get-HardDisk -vm $vmobject | Measure-Object -Sum CapacityGB).Sum)
     'Networks'=(Get-NetworkAdapter -VM $vmobject |Sort-Object NetworkName |Select -Unique -Expand NetworkName) -join '; '
     'OS'=($vmobject | Get-View).summary.config.guestFullName
  }
  $object=New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Prop $properties

  Export-Csv -Path $WorkDir\vms.csv -Append -Encoding UTF8 -InputObject $Object 
  Write-Output $Object
}
```

Comment: +1 but I'd also add that one should call `Get-VM $vmname` once, store the result in a variable, and then use it for all of the subsequent properties. It seems awfully inefficient to call get `Get-VM` 6 times for the same VM in one loop iteration.

Comment: @briantist Oh good lord, yes! Thank you for pointing that out, I got tunnel vision for the exact issue he was having I didn't even notice that. Please leave your comment, but I'll update the answer to reflect that for better visibility.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much. That is much closer to what I was originally imagining, but struggled with around getting the OS out. I don't recall, but I expect I was overcomplicating it. Thank you very much for the assistance. I bet that runs a lot faster too. :-)

Comment: Wow, much faster and exactly what I wanted.